# postgres removing user from role membership

Tags: postgresql

How do I drop a role member? My role name *tester* is member of role *postgres* (which I do not want). How do I remove this membership?

```
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of  
-----------+------------------------------------------------+------------
 tester    |                                                | {postgres}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

Answer (score 14):

With [REVOKE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html) e.g.:

```
REVOKE postgres FROM tester;
```

Answer (score -3):

Check the existence of a member role in another role.

```
SELECT r.rolname  as username, r1.rolname as "role", roleid, member
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r JOIN pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
ON (m.member = r.oid)
JOIN pg_roles r1 ON (m.roleid=r1.oid)
WHERE r.rolname = 'tester' AND r1.rolname = 'postgres';
```

### Solution

```
REVOKE postgres FROM tester;

-- Or also
REVOKE "postgres" FROM "tester";
```

*Notice that 'postgres' and 'tester' does not work.*

---

**WARNING**:

> Hack in the internals is extremely bad advice

But in case the code helps you to do something else that does not have a native implementation.

```
DELETE FROM pg_auth_members WHERE
member = (SELECT member
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r JOIN pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        ON (m.member = r.oid)
        JOIN pg_roles r1 ON (m.roleid=r1.oid)
        WHERE r.rolname = 'tester' AND r1.rolname = 'postgres') AND
roleid = (SELECT roleid
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r JOIN pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        ON (m.member = r.oid)
        JOIN pg_roles r1 ON (m.roleid=r1.oid)
        WHERE r.rolname = 'tester' AND r1.rolname = 'postgres');
```

GL

[Source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/136869/154867)

Comment: Why write code to hack in the internals when a simple `revoke` will do? This is extremely bad advice.

Comment: REVOKE DOES NOT WORK !!! And if I want to do it at a low level, what is your problem? Also, if Postgres allows editing for a reason, that decision precedes your opinions. And if only to get the members I have to access that way as in this answer [https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/136869/154867], that remains for the edit.

Comment: Did you remember to commit after revoke?

Comment: I found the problem, I was using 'postgres' instead of postgres or "postgres" which do work. Sorry. I will proceed to edit the answer.

Comment: Updated answer with suggested.