# PostgreSQL, display role members

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, role

Is there a way to visualize which users are mebers of a role in PostgreSQL / pgAdminIII, like

```
role: council_stuff
members:
    Harry
    Ben
    Steve
    Melinda
```

Comment: see also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56096/how-to-get-all-roles-that-a-user-is-a-member-of-including-inherited-roles

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To get all members of all roles:

```
SELECT r.rolname as username,r1.rolname as "role"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r JOIN pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
ON (m.member = r.oid)
JOIN pg_roles r1 ON (m.roleid=r1.oid)                                  
WHERE r.rolcanlogin
ORDER BY 1;
```

Add `r1.rolname='council_stuff'` to filter on only that one.

Be aware that users themselves are "roles" in postgresql parlance (there used to be "users and groups" in older versions, but this have been unified into roles).

Here the difference is made between a user and a role with `rolcanlogin` boolean column, which corresponds o the interpretation that a user is a role that has the LOGIN permission.

The two `JOIN` can be turned into `LEFT JOIN` to add the users who aren't member of any role:

```
SELECT r.rolname as username,r1.rolname as "role"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
ON (m.member = r.oid)
LEFT JOIN pg_roles r1 ON (m.roleid=r1.oid)                                  
WHERE r.rolcanlogin
ORDER BY 1;
```